# Strange output of "TypeError" of "GeoDataFrame" when only calling the range

Tags: python, for-loop, range, typeerror, geopandas

I come across a strange error when using `range(a, b)` in Python, which says I made a `TypeError` for calling `GeoDataFrame`, while there should not be any `GeoDataFrame` involved.

The process should not be related to `GeoDataFrame`. For example, I tried to print the `range(0,2)`, while getting the TypeError. No error would happen if using the `list` directly (e.g.`[1,2,3]`)[image]

(The following are my codes for reference. They are generally for generating a network in Python-igraph from shapefiles.)

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import igraph as ig

# Import data
data = gpd.read_file(r"\streets.shp")
print(data)
data2 = gpd.read_file(r"\intersections.shp")
range = gpd.read_file(r"\streets_range.shp")
OD_matrix = gpd.read_file(r"\OD_data.gpkg", driver="GPKG")

# Make sure the intersection IDs are integers
data["Inter_ID0"] = data["Inter_ID0"].astype(int)
data["Inter_ID1"] = data["Inter_ID1"].astype(int)

# Create graph
G = ig.Graph()
G.add_vertices(data2.shape[0])
G.add_edges(list(zip(data["Inter_ID0"], data["Inter_ID1"])))
G.es['Length'] = data["Length"]

# Calculate shortest paths
for v in range(0, 7506):
    path1 = G.get_shortest_paths(v, to=None, weights="Length", mode='all', output='epath')
    path2 = G.get_shortest_paths(v, to=None, weights="Length", mode='all', output='vpath')
    ......
```

Results:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 2
      1 matrix = pd.DataFrame([])
----> 2 for v in range(0, 7506):
      3     path1 = G.get_shortest_paths(v, to=None, weights="Length", mode='all', output='epath')
      4     path2 = G.get_shortest_paths(v, to=None, weights="Length", mode='all', output='vpath')

TypeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object is not callable
```

(So the traceback also did not refer to any line where GeoDataFrame is involved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a variable to the keyword `range` earlier in your code. Change the name of that variable.

```
streets_range = gpd.read_file(r"\streets_range.shp")
```